# Long string in InputField is cut when stored

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, input-field, user-interaction

I'm coding an Android game in Unity and I want the user to be able to input a long string in an Input Field and then display it in another Text component.

The problem is that although the Input Field text limit is set to 0 (so infinite according to Unity's documentation) when I type a very long string it cuts it to the visible part so for example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Will be cut like this :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Because the frame of the text field isn't big enough.

It's not really a programming issue but I hope someone here can help me fix it.

Comment: You need to add your code to your question. We can't get to the issue without that

Comment: The code I run doesn't interfere with the behavior of the input field, the only thing it does is get the text from the input field.

Comment: Unless a code is not the problem, you still need to add the code. You also need to mention when you want to textinput to display in your text component.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer!

I was getting the input field text through the **text component** of the input field

```
string text = my_UI_ellement.GetComponent<InputField>().textComponent.text;
```

But the **text component** is the component the input field uses to **render the text on screen** which means that **the overflowing text** either horizontally or vertically **isn't stored in the text component.**

So instead I used the **text** component directly:

```
string text = my_UI_ellement.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
```

And the retrieved string was the full string!

Comment: I would abvote this because it is probably a mistake a lot of beginners might make. But you didn't add your code example to your question so nobody actually got a chance to find this mistake